# How to generate a list of all graphs with maximum degree D and diameter smaller than P?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I'm looking for a clever algorithm to generate a list of all possible graphs with maximum degree D and diameter at most P such that any two graphs of this list are not isomorphic. Any ideas ?